# why we are storing the client secret as plain text in database in spring OAuth 2.0?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am a new guy to Spring OAuth 2.0. We would like to use the "Client credentials" grant type for our resource server .While implementing this type we are not sure about the maintaining the "Client ID" and "Client Secret" as plain text in the databases. Somebody will hack these client ID and client secret and may miss use these if we store client secret as plain text.

Can any one please let us know whether is there any way to keep these values "Client ID" and "Client Secret" in the encrypted format?.

Is there any default option available in Spring OAuth 2.0 to encode and decode it?

Please let usknow is there any specific reason to store the client secret as plain text?

Thanks,

Comment: The data you save is used to authenticate the client so you  need to be able to read it on the server and so everyone hacking your server can. OAuth is designed in a way that the stored information (the authtoken) can only be used with the service it it was issued for. If someone hacks your server you need to reset thise tokens anyway after you recovered from that hack.

Comment: Just add a `PasswordEncoder` like you normally would do for user/password.

Comment: Hi,

The thing that we are stuck is that if we can use "PasswordEncoder" to encode the client secret while creating,Spring OAuth 2 library will create the access token by taking the encoded client secret.Mean we are not able to find out that Spring OAuth 2.0 library pick up the encoded client secret from the database and decode it and them generate the access token.we also need this thing in the resource server too.

Please let me know is there any way to do this in spring OAuth 2.0 so that we can keep the client secret in secure?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You MUST NOT save the client secret as a plain text.
The client secret MUST NOT be decryptable. 
Just use org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder and it will encrypt client secret using [BCrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) algorithm.